# Div's width whose content was added through JavaScript is 0

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am trying to get the width of a Div (with img inside) from JavaScript. So first i add the img tag manually in html within the dev, and do getComputedSytle on div which gives me the calculated width of the div that's about img's width (as desired) (i haven't set any width in CSS and display is inline-block of the div). But when i add the img tag from Javascrpt using div.innerhtml property, the width of div results out to be 0. Is there a workaround for this. I don't want to calculate the img's width as the content inside the div can by dynamic.

> Img being added from JS

```js
let div=document.querySelector("div")

div.innerHTML=`<img class="child" src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">`

divWidth = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(div).width)

console.log("divWidth", divWidth)
```

```css
div{
    background-color: teal;
    display:inline-block;
    height: 400px;
  }

img{
    background-color: red;
    max-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
 <div ></div>
```

> Img manually added

```js
let div=document.querySelector("div")
let divWidth = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(div).width)
console.log("divWidth", divWidth)
```

```css
div{
    background-color: teal;
    display:inline-block;
    height: 400px;

}

img{
    max-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
 <div>
 <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
 </div>
```

Edit: The behaviour also seems to be different depending on whether the image is loaded from url or hard drive or whether the code is being run on stackoverflow or my pc;.

Comment: In the first snippet, the image isn't loaded yet; you need to add the image element, select it, then assign an `onload` event handler to it and measure the div inside.

Comment: @ChrisG thanks bro, can u help me with the code snippet

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/mtjqkgy8/ (note that all code that relies on `divWidth` needs to be inside that anonymous function!)

Comment: Chris G, you should add it as an answer

Comment: yus makes sense